# Error while set language, despite package is already installed

Tags: captions, languages, rmarkdown

I'm writing a document in R markdown and using latex for figures and tables. I need the captions in Portuguese, so I try this:

R markdown file:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
      includes:
            in_header: mystyles.sty
  html_document: rmarkdown::github_document
  word_document: default
---
```

mystyles.sty file:

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
```

However, when I build the document using `rmarkdown::render("filename.Rmd")` I got the error:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `portuguese'. Either you misspelled it (babel) or the language definition file portuguese.ldf was not found.
```

As I'm in Ubuntu, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-portuguese
```

which returns that I already has this package installed:

```
texlive-lang-portuguese is already the newest version (2015.20160223-1).
```

I also tried to run `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european` which returns the same

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `portuges`? At least that is the name of the `.ldf` file that seems to be associated with that language

Comment: I just tried it. It didn't work either

Comment: No many of us are using rmarkdown. Can you provide the generated latex file? That would be a lot easier for us to work with.

Comment: Sorry @daleif, your first suggestion did work! In portuguese the name of the language is `portugues`, I read your recommendation quickly and wrote this in the code. However, I note now that you instead wrote `portuges`, which, weirdly, is neither English or Portuguese but IT WORKS. Many thanks!

Comment: This wouldn’t be the cause of your error (You seem to need to install some packages.) but it’s generally a good idea to pass language options to the `\documentclass`. It will pass them to every loaded package, and packages other than `babel` might need them.

Comment: Did you somewhere specify the language using a macro, instead of its plain text name? Possibility that it is an expansion problem, in which the document code does not expand the macro, but the babel error code does expand it. I have seen something similar with polyglossia language variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The babel name for Portuguese seems to be `portugues`, at leat that that is the name of the language file `portuges.ldf`.

So try `portuges` instead

Comment: `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}` works for me in a full texlive without problems. So something is wrong/missing in the tex-system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The versions in the Ubuntu packages? I only use upstream